# Regular expression for matching a sequence?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

My text includes phrases inside a known pattern, for example: `#%some phrase%#`, the phrase can be anything (obviously it will not include the pattern `'%#'`).
Now, I want to build a regex (in php) that will match a sequence of 2 or more phrases (with or without white spaces between them), so if, for example, my text is:

```
#%jjj jjj%#  kkjjkkjj kkjjkkjj  #%kkk kkk%# #%ttt mmm%#
```

I want the regex to match:

```
#%kkk kkk%# #%ttt mmm%#
```

I've tried this regex: `/(?:#%.+?(?!%#).%#\s*){2,}/`

But for some strange reason it matches the whole string, and ignores the negative lookahead.

Furthermore, my complete task would be to match a sequence of phrases with up to 1 character between them (in addition to the white spaces).

How to implement it?

Test cases:

Text:

> #%Prime target%# #%Online stuff%# English Deutsch Norsk Svenska Suomi English AU English CA #%Home%# #%About Us%# #%Fair Play%# #%Promotions%#

Should match:

> 1. #%Prime target%# #%Online stuff%#
> 2. #%Home%# #%About Us%# #%Fair Play%# #%Promotions%#

Text:

> #%Prime target%# English Deutsch Norsk Svenska Suomi English AU English CA #%Home%# | #%About Us%# | #%Fair Play%# | #%Promotions%#

Should match:

> 1. #%Home%# | #%About Us%# | #%Fair Play%# | #%Promotions%#

Comment: I wrote that "my complete task would be to match a sequence of phrases with up to 1 character between them (in addition to the white spaces)."

Comment: I updated my answer based on your test inputs, see if that is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify your regex:

```
(?:#%(?:(?!%#).)+?.%#\s*)(?:.?\s*#%(?:(?!%#).)+?.%#\s*)+
```

Wrapping the `.+?` capture within the lookbehind at `(?: )` group forces the lazy match to not match `(?!%#)` while proceeding, it's also why your original regex does not work.

Also, clone it into a separate group with match prefix `.?` for a character to be acceptable between groups.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hX6gL8/6)!

> Test case:
>
> `#%jjj jjj%#  kkjjkkjj kkjjkkjj  #%kkk kkk%# #%ttt mmm%#`
>
> Match:
> `#%kkk kkk%# #%ttt mmm%#`

Comment: it seems to work! I will have to test it with more complex text to make sure... can you explain to me again why this modification made the difference? I didn't use a lookbehind, but a negative lookahead, the (?: ) is just a non capturing group.

Comment: Problem was: in `(?:#%.+?(?!%#).%#\s*){2,}`, your lookbehind is practically useless. `.+?` tells the engine to go character by character until it can reach the next sequence - `(?!%#).` That means as long as a section of the string starts with a `#%`, and another section of the string starts with a `#%`, your old regex would match from the first to the final `%#` in the String. Which means, everything. Mine addresses this by enforcing `(?!%#)` on `.+?` match.

Answer (score 1):

based on your test inputs I came up with this regex, short and still effective

```
/((?:#%[^#]*%#(?:\s.\s|\s)){2,})/g
```

test string

`test 1`

`#%Prime target%# #%Online stuff%# English Deutsch Norsk Svenska Suomi English AU English CA #%Home%# #%About Us%# #%Fair Play%# #%Promotions%#`

`test 2`

`#%Prime target%# English  Deutsch Norsk Svenska Suomi English AU English CA #%Home%# | #%About Us%# | #%Fair Play%# | #%Promotions%#`

result

- MATCH 1

  1. [8-42]  `#%Prime target%# #%Online stuff%#`
- MATCH 2

  1. [100-151]   `#%Home%# #%About Us%# #%Fair Play%# #%Promotions%#`
- MATCH 3

  1. [236-293]   `#%Home%# | #%About Us%# | #%Fair Play%# | #%Promotions%#`

try demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/wB6mO6/7)

Comment: @pushpraj I think you didn't understand me, I don't want to match each phrase, I want to match the whole sequence (if it includes more than 2 phrases with or without white spaces and optionally 1 character between them)

Comment: in that case simply modify the same to `/(?<=\s|^)((#%[^#]*?%#)\s*.?\s*((?2)))/g` then the first capture group is what you need [try here](http://regex101.com/r/wB6mO6/4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
/(?:.*?#%.*?%#.*?)(#%.*%#)/g
```

It finds first `#%...%#` (ungreedy) and then match the next one `#%...%#` (greedy)

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jV3mG1/2)**

Comment: but it also matches anything between the phrases, I only want to match a sequence of phrases as explained with up to 1 character and white spaces between them.